# Batch file to retrieve one line at a time and then loop through directories of files to find matches to each line

Tags: batch-file

I have a file of keys and values and wish to step though each key and see if that key occurs at least once (or provide count) in at least one file.

First file looks like this:

```
"foo.bar" : "hello world",
"lorem.ipsum" : "a quick brown fox",
....
```

and I want to sweep all .js files in subdirectories to see if "foo.bar" is used and provide a count for that key; then take the next key "lorem.ipsum" and sweep all js files in subdirectories to see if it is used and then provide a count.

I get parts of the soltion working but do not get the whole thing working together at once.  Challenges has veen findstr does not use /c for count and needing () to keep everything in order.

The outer part I cna get to iterate thourhg each of the lines of the string file...

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=:" %%a in (src/dict/strs_en.json) do (
    findstr /s %%a c:\foo\bar\my\code\*.js
)
```

but internally I need something more like an example that was gien elsewhere in stackoverflow:

```
for /F "delims=" %G in ('findstr /I /S /M "foo.bar" "%CD%\*.js"') do @find /I /C "home." "%~G" | findstr /V /R "^$"
```

where "foo.bar" is really my %%a

In the end, desired output would be either (I just want ot know what is used and what is not used)

```
"foo.bar"  2
"lorem.ipsum" 1
"dolor.et"  0
```

or

```
"foo.bar" 
- file1.js
- file2.js

"lorem.ipsum"
- file3.js

"dolor.et"
-

"test.me"
- file2.js
- file3.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the output in `output.log` give you something you can work with after running this batch file:

```bat
@(For /F Skip^=1^ Delims^=^" %%A In (src\dict\strs_en.json) Do @(
    Echo="%%A" & FindStr/SMC:"%%A" C:\foo\bar\my\code\*.js & Echo=))>output.log
```

Comment: That gives me the list of all the files with that extension along with their directory structure and lists them as many times as I have strings in the original file

Comment: Thank you @compo, A hybrid approach of what I had and your very much appreciated example gave me `@(for /f "skip=1 delims=:" %%a in (src/dict/strs_en.json) do @(
 Echo=%%a & findstr/s %%a c:\foo\bar\my\code\*.js & Echo=))>output.log`  gives me cleaner results for the "key" line, but I am hoping there is a way to clean up the second half that is currently printing out `"foo.bar"  
C:\dev\src\foo\bar\src\foo\bar\lorem\ipsum\dolor\et\foo.js:                            <h1 className="welcomeClassHeader">translate('foo.bar')</h1>`

Comment: I do not reall need the  `<h1 className="welcomeClassHeader">translate('foo.bar')</h1>` because it is not useful and takes up a heck of a lot of space.

Comment: You have changed my command by removing the `/M` option I gave to `FindStr` in order to output the filename only, _(that is why it's outputting line content)_. I have updated my answer to ignore the first line of the `.json` file to match your comment, there should be no other change you need to make unless you've failed to provide some other important piece of information.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That is perfect and you were 100% right that it was the m that I failed to include as you advised that once applied worked beautifully.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Please consider marking my answer as accepted if it solved your problem. You can do that by clicking on the tick to the left of my answer.